# Random Quote Generator for a simple app, Please help :)

Tags: java, eclipse, random, generator

I appreciate any input you have. I am new to coding and have managed to make a text play app (displays a line of text in a random size and colour). I was trying to create a random quote app and have two buttons. I want to use them to select a quote from two separate lists. How would I do this? The only other experience of buttons I have is with another beginner app I made, which added or took away one number from a counter:

```
package com.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FOREVERAPHONE extends Activity {
    int counter;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_foreveraphone);

        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter += 1;
                display.setText("counter");
            }
        });
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter -= 1;
                display.setText("counter");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Please help! I have spent hours and hours trying to figure it out! Thank you so much.

Comment: How do I make the buttons select a random quote?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a class called Random that you can use to simulate the generation of a random number.

Try this:

```
package com.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList<E>;

public class FOREVERAPHONE extends Activity {
    int selector;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display;
    // List of random quotes
    ArrayList<String> listOfRandomQuotes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_foreveraphone);

        listOfRandomQuotes = new ArrayList<String>();
        listOfRandomQuotes.add("A penny saved is a penny earned.");
        listOfRandomQuotes.add("You must be the change you wish to see in the world.");
        listOfRandomQuotes.add("I have decided to stick with love. Hate is too great a burden to bear.");
        listOfRandomQuotes.add("By failing to prepare, you are preparing to fail.");

        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Random randomNumber = new Random();
                selector = randomNumber.nexInt(4);
                display.setText(listOfRandomQuotes.get(selector));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Each time you hit the "add" button it should pick a random quote and display it.

**Note:** Be sure not to set the OnClickListener for a view more than once!

Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks amazing Don. Going to try and get it working tonight. Seriously thanks.

Comment: Glad to help! If it does end up working for you, please don't forget to mark it as the correct answer! :) Best wishes!

Comment: Right, that's brilliant. Added a menu. Always hated coding and computers, but starting to enjoy this Don. :)

Comment: Thanks! I definitely wasn't what you would call "tech savvy" when I first started, but coding grows on you. Just keep at it. ;)